# Background drawable in RelativeLayout is not showed on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have added a drawable as a background to a RelativeLayout object (drawable with bitmap).
This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/FirstSlideFrame"
                android:background="@drawable/background_darken">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and background_darken.xml(the drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/new_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

It works fine on Android 2.2, 2.3, 4.2.2 but on Android 5.1.1 the image is not showed.

Any Idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Haim.

**EDIT** (blurred some parts...):

4.2.2
[image]
5.1.1
[image]

Updated activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity"
                    android:id="@+id/FirstSlideFrame">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/new_bg"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:id="@+id/LogoText" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:textSize="72dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    fbutton:buttonColor="#42A5F5"
                    fbutton:shadowColor="#1E88E5"
                    fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                    fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
                    fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum scelerisque turpis vel aliquet mattis."
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you give us how the drawable new_bg look like?

Comment: @ImMathan new_bg is a png file.

Comment: @intellij-amiya I am not understand you answer

Comment: @Haim127 bitmap xmlns:android is not supported in API Level 21

Comment: @intellij-amiya What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `BitmapDrawable` is deprecated from API level 18. If you see [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) Its not advisable to use it. So that it will have different behaviour in latest os versions.

Comment: OK. So what can I do? I am want to use resources files and not writing code for the background.

Comment: you can directly use `android:background="@drawable/your_image_resource"`. What you have to achieve?

Comment: @Haim127 is there any problem if you use android:background="@drawable/your_image_resource"

Comment: @ ImMathan @IntelliJ-Amiya I need the gravity so I have put it in a drawable. There is a way to put directly background from file with center horizontal gravity? Thanks

Comment: No you can't. You have to use an `ImageView` as a first child with height and width `match_parent` and you can set `android:background="@drawable/your_image_resource"` and don't forget to give `scaleType` as centre_crop or centre_inside as per your need.

Comment: @ImMathan Still not working :( ( In Android 4.2.2 it works but in the fu**ing 5.1.1 it stays with gray background)

Comment: Can you post two screen shots, one from 4.2.2 and one from 5.1.1.?

Comment: @ImMathan Yeah, I will upload them in a few minutes

Comment: @Haim127 Great. Can you update the xml of the activity